# Batch rename: skipping already renamed files

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, file-rename

so in one other recent question i needed to find a solution to bulk renaming files by adding .ab into the filename. I succeeded in doing that, but now i face a different problem. Every time i run the batch file, it appends .ab to all the files even those, already renamed. I tried fixing the problem in the following way, which doesn't work.

```
rem @echo off

FOR /R "C:\Users\" %%G in (*.txt) DO (
  %%G|findstr /i /L ".ab">nul
  IF errorlevel 1 (
    REN "%%G" "%%~nG.ab.txt"
  ) ELSE (
    skip %%G
  )
)

pause
```

Essentially i need to check if the file name already contains ".ab" in its name and then either skip or add .ab depending on the result. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `For /F` loop, instead of `For /R`. In addition, instead of using the `Dir` command with its `/S` option, *(which will output items ending with `.txt*`)*, use `Where` with its `/R` option instead, *(which will output items ending with `.txt`)*.

Single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example, (excludes those basenames ending with, *not containing*, `.ab`):

```batch-file
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('^""%__AppDir__%where.exe" /R "C:\Users" "*.txt" 2^>NUL^|"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /IV "\.ab\.txt$"^"')Do @Ren "%%G" "%%~nG.ab%%~xG"
```

*Don't forget to change `C:\Users` and/or both instances of `.txt` and `ab` as/if necessary.*