# Skipping Already Renamed Files in Batch File For Loop

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, file-rename

I have been trying to find a way to rename any/all subtitle files (.srt, .idx, and .sub) by putting a prefix (ZZSubs_) to all the files matching this case. I also want the batch file not to execute/skip renaming if it is run accidentally a second time. With the code below, every time I run the batch file it keeps prepending "ZZSubs_" to the already renamed files even though I am checking for the "ZZSubs_" with the IF NOT EXIST and the asterisk * symbol.

```
@ECHO OFF
CD /D "%~dp0"

for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.SRT *.IDX *.SUB') do (
        REM Rename Subtitle files with a ZZSubs_ filename prefix
        IF NOT EXIST "ZZSubs_*%%i" RENAME "%%i" "ZZSubs_%%i"
    )
PAUSE
```

This is very simliar to the question asked below, but I am also looking to perform this recursively in all sub directories of a given folder and not to a specific, hard-coded folder path:
[Batch rename: skipping already renamed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60580951/batch-rename-skipping-already-renamed-files)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.SRT *.IDX *.SUB ^|findstr /B /V /I "zzsubs_"') do`

Comment: Why not filter it out within your parenthesized command, e.g. `'dir /b *.SRT *.IDX *.SUB ^| findstr /I /V  "ZZSubs_"'` or similar. _(I didn't advise the `/B` option here because I read your question, and noted that your intent will be to use a recursive `/s` option with `dir`, and the results would therefore be fully qualified absolute paths, hence negating the `/B`eginning option)_

Comment: *N. B.:* Change `dir /B` to `dir /B /A:-D-H-S` to exclude directories as well as hidden and system files matching the mask…

Answer (score 2):

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.SRT *.IDX *.SUB ^|findstr /v /b "ZZSubs_"') do (
```

should be the change you need. This sends the `dir` output to `findstr` (the caret is required to tell `cmd` that the pipe is part of the command to be executed, not of the `for`). The `findstr` command finds all the lines that do NOT (`/v`) begin (`/b`) with the string.

Suppose with your code, you executed it with a file named `ZZSubs_one.srt`. Now - does `ZZSubs_ZZSubs_one.srt` exist?

Comment: I tried the above, but it only works when there is an SRT, IDX, or SUB file in the same folder as the batch file, but will not recursively go down into the subfolders to rename the specific files with those file extensions. It also removed the .srt file extension from the files. But it did only execute once after several runs, which is a step in the right direction!

And with the original code, a file named ZZSubs_one.srt would be named again as ZZSubs_ZZSubs_one.srt. Similar to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519458/for-loop-in-batch-file-renames-one-file-twice

Comment: @mbielech5 start by reading the help file for the commands.  Open up a command prompt and type: `DIR /?` and `FINDSTR /?`.  Apparently giving you an answer is not working so maybe teaching you to fish will.

Comment: @Magoo I managed to fix the file extension from getting erased during the rename using the `%~xi` variable. Here's what I have now: 

`@ECHO OFF
CD /D "%~dp0"

for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s *.SRT *.IDX *.SUB ^|findstr /v /b "ZZSubs_"') do (
        REM Rename Subtitle files with a ZZSubs_ filename prefix
  RENAME "%%~i" "ZZSubs_%%~ni%%~xi"
    )
PAUSE`

To answer your question, yes it still appends `ZZSubs_` to the currently existing `ZZSubs_`-named files, making the new filename `ZZSubs_ZZSubsEnglish.srt`.
My apologies, my batch file writing is at a very novice level.

Comment: No requirement for apologies - we were all novices once, & you've done very well. I missed the subdirectory requirement. You could add ` 2^>nul ` into your `dir` command to suppress the error message if no such files exist. Also you could use `%%~nxi` instead of `%%~ni%%~xi`. My question was rhetorical but I muffed it. The point is that your original code looked for a file named `ZZSubs_ZZSubs_one.srt` if `ZZSubs_one.srt` existed. Not found, so rename... A small potential bug: Suppose `one.srt` exists & is renamed. If `one.txt` reappears, *that* file will be renamed to an existing filename...

Answer (score 1):

This should work in a `windows` `batch-file` run by `cmd`. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available. When you are confident that the files will be renamed correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Rename-Item` command.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Set-Location -Path %~dp0;" ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Path *.SRT,*.IDX,*.SUB |" ^
    "ForEach-Object { if ($_.Name -notmatch '^ZZSubs_') { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ('ZZSubs_'+$_.Name) -WhatIf } }"
```

Comment: Not sure why `powershell` solutions are downvoted in batch questions. This will work in a `batch-file` as hybrid just as `vbscript` and many other external functions are used in `batch-file`s. Perhaps just update the file extensions as per the OP, @lit.

Comment: @Gerhard, this `batch-file` uses an executable, `powershell.exe`, that is part of the system. What is the measure of naming something "hybrid?" I agree that `powershell.exe` is an external executable from `cmd.exe`. But, so are `findstr.exe`, `xcopy.exe`, and `ipconfig.exe`. Does use of those create a "hybrid?" The goal is to make something that works. Right?